# How to change a div class after scrolling past, and then change it back to original when completing the same scrolling action for a second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html I've got a `div` that changes its class when the user scrolls past it (and the `div` becomes out of view), such that when the user scrolls back up the page the class is changed.

I would like to have that `div` class reverted to original the second time the user scrolls back up, but just can't figure out a way to do so. I'm trying to find a way for it to work in such a way that the effect repeats and the class alternates every time it comes back into view.

I'm doing this with two scripts at the moment. The first one works and changes the class of the `div` when the user scrolls back up:

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    var scroll1 = $(window).scrollTop();  // how many pixels have been scrolled
    var os1 = $('#div1').offset().top;  // pixels to top of div1
    var ht1 = $('#div1').height();  // height of div1 in pixels
    if (scroll > os1 + ht1) {
      $('#div1').removeClass('english').addClass('japanese');
    }
  });
</script>
```

But the second one doesn't seem to do anything at all:

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    var scroll2 = $(window).scrollTop();
    var os2 = $('#div1').offset().top;
    var ht2 = $('#div1').height();
    var class1 = document.getElementsByClassName('japanese')[0].className;
    if (scroll > os1 + ht1 && class1 == 'japanese') {
      $('#div1').removeClass('japanese').addClass('english');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like there's a typo in the condition on the second script, could that be the problem? You're using `if (scroll > os1 + ht1 && class1 = 'japanese') { ... }` but I guess it should be `if (scroll > os1 + ht1 && class1 == 'japanese') { ... }`

Comment: Hi Eduardo, sorry for the typo but this doesn't seem to resolve the problem :(

Comment: Ok Felix, I'm sorry it didn't work. I've fixed the typo just to make it clear that the problem is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening because you have the same conditions in both of the functions. 
**For the second condition use this instead**

```
if(scroll < os1 + ht1)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help, but this doesn't work sadly